# Inplace Multi-Level Select Jquery Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Anyone know a jquery plugin a la deviantart.com inplace multi-level select box, the one you see when you select the categories

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what select box you are referring to?

Comment: looks like they have removed it from the website, basically a selectbox with multilevel capabilities, all i could find on the web is either a single level select box + styling or a multi level drop down menu that would work best for navigation, not selection

Comment: this is exactly what i want to accomplish http://bozhao.info/web_examples/columnNavi.html but i am looking for a more comprehensive pluging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply take one of the various suckerfish-style menu scripts and use it to select your categories.

[Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish) looks pretty nice.